# Instantiate parameterized type using Class.forName

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have the following classes:

```
public class B {
}

public class A<B> {
}
```

How do I instantiate class `A` using `Class.forName`, given that I have two string variables:

```
String classNameA = "A";
String classNameB = "B";
```

Comment: Class B is hiding the Generic type B in A<B>

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733799/generics-and-class-forname

Answer (score 6):

Due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), there won't be any generic classes at run time.

For instance, the following piece of code will output `class java.util.ArrayList` without generics:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
System.out.println(list.getClass());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Class<B> bClass = (Class<B>) Class.forName(classNameB);
B b = bClass.newInstance();
Class<A<B>> aClass = (Class<A<B>>) Class.forName(classNameA);
A<B> a = aClass.newInstance();
```

The type parameter  of type A does not exist during runtime, so you can cast `aClass` to `Class<A<B>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Since all instances of a generic class share the same class object, the type parameter doesn't matter to the runtime, so you can simply do:

```
Class.forName("A").newInstance();
```

and cast the result to whatever type you need.